# Rationale of Orthodox groups who remained in the Synagogue Council of America

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, synagogue, jewish-american-history

The opposition many had to  Orthodox groups joining the Synagogue Council of America is well known. It remains easy to find articles explaining the opposition that were written back then in Torah or haskafa journals that  are still easily accessible today.

What about the opposite perspective? Can anyone summarize or link to statements/writings from Orthodox groups or Rabbis  who remained on the Synagogue Council of America explaining why they felt their participation in that group was not problematic? It seems many (especially Haredi/hasidic) rabbanim believe giving cultural legitimacy to heretics, even ones of the Jewish nation, is wrong.

Comment: I am not sure this is in scope. Is it really about Judaism? If yes can you explain the halachic issues involved so those of us not familiar with the context can understand? Or is it purely historical/sociological (which might not be in scope)?

Comment: @mbloch it sounds hashkafic to me.